# JQuery disable next select

Tags: php, jquery

On .mSubIndex being changed to 1, I want to disable the next select box. The following code is not working. I'm having a problem addressing the select element - not sure whether it's anything to do with it being in a table

```
echo "<form action='menu-add.php' method='post'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input name='mIndex' value=''></td>";
echo "<td><input name='mSubIndex' class='mSubIndex' value=''></td>";
echo "<td><input name='mTitle' value=''></td>";
echo "<td class='pag'>";
echo "<select name='pageName' class='pageName'>";
echo "<option value='0'>Please Choose Page</option>";
  foreach (glob('../*.php') as $pageFile) {
    $pageFile = substr($pageFile, 3);
    echo "<option value='".$pageFile."'>".$pageFile."</option>";
  }
echo "</select>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submitAdd' value='Add'></td>";
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mSubIndex').on('input',function() {
  var $this = $(this)
  if ($this.val()==1) {
  $this.closest('form').find('.pageName').prop('disabled','disabled')
   }
 })
})
</script>
```

Comment: You have to write `if ($this.val()=="1") {` because the value of an input field always is a string.

Comment: Rightly or wrongly, the IF was firing anyway. That doesn't fix the problem, but thanks

Comment: try `$this.closest('form').find('.pageName').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: Already tried that. Just tried it again though but still the same

Comment: `console.log($this.closest('form').find('.pageName').length);` to test that the selector works.

Comment: console.log($this.closest('form').find('.pageName').length) returns  0

Comment: I don't see the opening `<table>` tag. I think to nest it correctly, the form tags should be around the table, not somewhere inside.

Comment: <table> tag exists earlier in the code (TLDR). The table contains multiple forms so inevitably they are within the table

Comment: Well the HTML isn't correctly nested. Who knows what happens if you do this.

Comment: <table><form> Seems to work ok because the other forms are functioning properly, so I don't think that is the problem. Thanks anyway